# npm publish of scoped packages to nexus fails

Tags: npm, nexus3

I have a problem publishing scoped npm-packages to a private nexus-repo.

The name of the package is @spike/core. The error message is:

```
npm notice Publishing to https://nexus.pitsfs.work/repository/npm-releases/
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - PUT https://nexus.pitsfs.work/repository/npm-releases/@spike%2fcore
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  '@spike/core@5.4.3' is not in this registry.
```

Environment:

- Nexus-Version: 3.57.0-01
- node-Version:  16.18.1
- npm-Version:   8.19.2
- Client Operating-System: Windows 10

It seems to be a problem with the escaped name of @spike/core (escaped to @spike%2fcore). To verify this, I've made the following change to the file c:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\libnpmpublish\lib\publish.js (which is executed, when `npm publish` is called):

```
  ...
  if (!spec.scope && opts.access === 'restricted') {
    throw Object.assign(
      new Error("Can't restrict access to unscoped packages."),
      { code: 'EUNSCOPED' }
    )
  }
  

  // ***************************************************************************  
  // !!! This added line fixed the problem (npm publish worked fine with it) !!!
  // ***************************************************************************  
  spec.escapedName = spec.escapedName.replace("%2f", "/");

  const metadata = buildMetadata(reg, pubManifest, tarballData, opts)

  try {
    return await npmFetch(spec.escapedName, {
      ...opts,
      method: 'PUT',
      body: metadata,
      ignoreBody: true,
    })
  } catch (err) {
  ...
```

Is there any configuration setting (in npm or nexus) to fix this without patching the file publish.js? I couldn't find anything in the nexus-documentation at https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager2/node-packaged-modules-and-npm-registries)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have an webserver in front of your Nexus then you should check it's config.
In Apache Webserver it's the option

```
AllowEncodedSlashes On
```

that maybe fix your problem. Maybe the option changed in newer Apache versions - ours was an old one: 2.2.15